# 5-bit AD converter

Tags: adc, converter

I just started working with AD converters and I got a trivial question about it.

In this one scenario, I have a 5-bit AD converter with a resolution of 312.5 mV. How can I calculate Vfs based on that? What does the equation look like?

Let's say you have a resolution of 0.5 V with a 4-bit AD Converter the answer should be 0.03125V but how do you get to that result, that's basically my question.
The equation or method is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up some terms.  Dissolution never applies to an ADC but the term resolution does.  A N bit convertor will have \$2^N\$ digital steps. 4 bits -> 16 steps.  These steps are called DN (short hand for digital number)  the (Voltage range of input)/\$2^N\$ = voltage resolution. 16V/16 = 1V per DN as an example.

Comment: It's my fault, I'm working with this in Swedish and that's what the translation gave me. It should be resolution, not dissolution. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what "dissolution" means in this context.

In your first example, I would think that 312.5 mV is the step size, or resolution, for a one-count change (also called one LSB). A 5-bit converter would have 2<sup>5</sup> = 32 steps, so the full-scale range would be 312.5 mV × 32 = 10.000 V.

In your second example, you seem to be saying that 0.5 V is the full-scale range, and that a 4-bit converter (2<sup>4</sup> = 16 steps) would have a step size, or resolution of 0.5 V / 16 = 31.25 mV.

Comment: It's my fault, I'm working with this in Swedish and that's what the translation gave me. It should be resolution, not dissolution. Sorry

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. My apologies for being so confusing